# guideline to generate boilerplate for xml like applicationContext?

Tags: eclipse, spring, spring-tool-suite

I know that it's possible to generate this schema above by selecting all these options in STS(Spring Tool Suite):

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
```

The point is I want to generate **beans** schema in **STS**(without any **copy-paste** as I have done it). If anyone faced with that, please guide me! Because copy-paste is senseless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In STS: Right click on some folder or package -> New -> Spring Bean Configuration File.
It will create empty xml with defined beans schema.

Comment: yes, that's it. Simple, I tried to find it in wrong place. Thank you! Very useful thing